# how to append a tag inside an html using java

Tags: java, jsoup, xsoup

I have an HTML

```
<h1><a>Hello I am html</a></h1>
```

what I want to achieve -

```
<h1><a>Hello I am <strong>html</strong></a></h1>
```

my code:-

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(HTML);

Element element = getElementUsingXpath(); // this is working fine 

String originalText = element.text();

String changedText = originalText.substring(0, 6 + 1)
                    + "<strong>"
                    + originalText.substring(6 + 1) +"</strong>";

element.text(changedText)
```

But I am getting this

```
Hello I am <strong>html</strong> //this is wrong
```

I was expecting it to be

> Hello I am **html**

Comment: You’re having <sptron> in te changedText

Comment: sorry typo mistake, please check it now

Comment: Since you want to write html and not text, you should probably try [the html(String) method](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html-java.lang.String-)

Comment: tons of thanks to @OHGODSPIDERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem got solved with the below code... suggested by @OHGODSPIDERS

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(HTML);

Element element = getElementUsingXpath(); // this is working fine 

String originalText = element.text();

String changedText = originalText.substring(0, 6 + 1)
                    + "<strong>"
                    + originalText.substring(6 + 1) +"</strong>";
```

> element.html(changedText)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to show another way of doing this, that uses the TextNode.splitText(offset) method. It's not really any simpler that Deepak's answer, but the method could be handy in other circumstances.

splitText splits a text node into two nodes at the specified string offset. After splitting, the node will contain the original text up to the offset, and will have a new text node sibling containing the text after the offset, which is returned.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<h1><a>Hello I am html</strong></h1>");
Element el = doc.selectFirst("a");
TextNode textNode = (TextNode) el.childNode(0);
textNode.splitText(textNode.text().indexOf("html")).wrap("<strong>");
System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

See the docs for [`TextNode#splitText(int)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html#splitText-int-) and [`Node#wrap(html)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#wrap-java.lang.String-).